# Storm - Dynamically increasing the executors

Tags: apache-storm

It seems to me that there are some limitations in storm.

Could you let me know below points are valid and true?

1. Number of workers should be less than or equal to number of executors
2. Number of executors should be less than or equal to number of tasks
3. Considering above 2 points, rebalancing is applicable only for moving executors or workers to other nodes etc...
4. Rebalancing does not help in increasing the tasks count dynamically
5. So Storm does not fully scalable as per the above points

Answer (score 4):

You can consider `tasks` as a running instance of a bolt/spout. That is fixed (static) and can never be changed while the topology is running ? The executors are actually the threads which can be changed dynamically.

if you set num tasks = 4 and executors = 2 then each thread will run 2 tasks. But tasks run serially on executors ( each thread will run one task at a time ).As a result even if you have 4 instances of a bolt all of them are not running at one time. So whats the use then ?

Creating multiple task per executor will provide you the flexibility to alter the number of executors using the `rebalance` command without killing the topology down. So in future if you add extra node to the cluster (or for whatever reason) you can easily change the number of executors to 4 so that now for each task there is a dedicated thread to handle that ( reason why `#threads <= #tasks` is true, because having more executors than task wont give any benefit). So now each 4 instances of your spout/bolt (called components) can run in parallel at one time . This is how storm scales.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your comments. So what I mean is scaling has a limit on number of tasks. If number of executors becomes equal to number of tasks which means each executor has only one task, then there is no point of scaling at all. At this point of time, we need to deploy a new topology altogether.

Comment: @HariprasadTaduru tasks are not always distributed equally among workers, storm tries to, but if you have an odd number of workers and an even number of tasks: it cannot be symmetric. Even if you don't distribute equally the load for one bolt/spout type, based on all bolts/spouts, it is indeed divided and your workers share the load of your topology (sometimes not very well depending on number of tasks/executors). It scales, if you want better, just use a higher number of tasks/executors depending on your number of workers so that the load can be better distributed in the cluster.